# Parallel.For & listcollectionview

Tags: c#, wpf, parallel-processing

I have a `listcollectionview` that I want to iterate over using `Parallel.For`

so far I have:

```
        public void HighlightLoggingLvl(
        LoggingLvl.ELoggingLvl loggingLvl, bool ebool) {
        Parallel.For(0, HighlighterCollectionView.Count, i => {
                 Log4NetLog cC =
                     HighlighterCollectionView.GetItemAt(i) as
                     Log4NetLog;

                 if (cC != null &&
                    cC.MyLoggingLvl.EloggingLvl == loggingLvl) {
                         if (ebool) {
                             cC.LogColour.SetColor(cC.MyLoggingLvl);
                          } else {
                                    cC.LogColour.Colour = Colors.Transparent;
                          }
                 }
         });
        HighlighterCollectionView.Refresh();
    }
```

Im getting the following Error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in      WindowsBase.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in     WindowsBase.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression:Path=Log4NetSearchEngineCompassLogView.Log4NetHighlighter.IsAllHighlighterEnable; DataItem='CompassLogView' (HashCode=57871897); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1') AggregateException:'System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
 at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess()
 at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.VerifyRefreshNotDeferred()
 at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.GetItemAt(Int32 index)
 at LogViewerViewModel.tools.highlighters.Log4NetHighlighter.<>c__DisplayClass1.<HighlightLoggingLvl>b__0(Int32 i) in c:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Pallas informatik\LogViewerV1\LogViewerViewModel\src\tools\highlighters\Log4NetHighlighter.cs:line 193
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass10.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__f(Object param0)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, Action`1 body)
        at LogViewerViewModel.tools.highlighters.Log4NetHighlighter.HighlightLoggingLvl(ELoggingLvl loggingLvl, Boolean ebool) in c:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Pallas informatik\LogViewerV1\LogViewerViewModel\src\tools\highlighters\Log4NetHighlighter.cs:line 190
 at LogViewerViewModel.tools.highlighters.Log4NetHighlighter.set_IsDebugHighlighterEnable(Boolean value) in c:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Pallas informatik\LogViewerV1\LogViewerViewModel\src\tools\highlighters\Log4NetHighlighter.cs:line 59
   at LogViewerViewModel.tools.highlighters.Log4NetHighlighter.set_IsAllHighlighterEnable(Boolean value) in c:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Pallas informatik\LogViewerV1\LogViewerViewModel\src\tools\highlighters\Log4NetHighlighter.cs:line 39
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
  at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
  at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess()
  at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.VerifyRefreshNotDeferred()
  at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.GetItemAt(Int32 index)
  at LogViewerViewModel.tools.highlighters.Log4NetHighlighter.<>c__DisplayClass1.<HighlightLoggingLvl>b__0(Int32 i) in c:\Users\Reza\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Pallas informatik\LogViewerV1\LogViewerViewModel\src\tools\highlighters\Log4NetHighlighter.cs:line 193
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass10.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__f(Object param0)<---
```

How Can I FIX this? (a code sample will be great)

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke your operations on UI Thread.

See the Dispatcher Class with the [invoke method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx)

or
[Understanding dispatcher in WPF](http://weblogs.asp.net/pawanmishra/archive/2010/06/06/understanding-dispatcher-in-wpf.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use parallel processing to update UI elements. Only the main thread of your application has access rights to the UI. It is possible to call `Invoke` on the checkboxes but for the work you are doing, what is the point of doing it in parallel? It won't buy you any performance.

I recommend using just a regular `for` loop rather than `Parallel.For`.

Comment: I can't use the regular `for`, the list is large and the UI Freezes.

Comment: You may wonder if it's good UI design to have so many checkboxes that the UI would freeze if you iterated over it... Either way, you cannot make this any faster by doing it in parallel, even if you do use Invoke.